# Adding observations as proportions on a horizontal barplot in R using text() function

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I cannot figure out how to get the percentage of responses at the end of the bars. I know I'm missing something within the `text()` function, just not sure what exactly I'm missing. Thank you!

```
#Training/Specialty Barplot
trainbarplot <- barplot(table(PSR$training), horiz = TRUE,
main="Respondent Distribution of Training", cex.main = 1.1, font.main = 2,
cex.lab = 0.8, cex.names = 0.4, font.axis = 4, las = 2,
xlab="Response Frequency", xlim=c(0, 40), cex.axis = 0.8,
border="black",
col=rgb (0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6),
density=c(50,40,30) , angle=c(9,11,36)
)

text(trainbarplot, table(PSR$training) - 3,
     labels=paste(round(proportions(table(PSR$training))*100, 0), "%"))
```

[image: Training/Specialty Bar Plot w/ Squished Percentage Labels]

Answer (score 0):

### Generate data

I generated some sample data to replicate your problem. Please note that you should always try to provide an example dataset :)

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, mean=10, sd=2), y = LETTERS[1:20])
```

### Plot the data

Here's a plot that follows the same structure as your code:

```
bp <- barplot(df1$x, names.arg = df1$y,  col = df1$colour, horiz = T)
text(x= df1$x+0.5, y= bp, labels=paste0(round(df1$x),"%"), xpd=TRUE)
```

### Using ggplot2

You can also plot your data using `ggplot2`. For instance, you could first create a new column in your dataset with information on the labels...

```
df1$perc <- paste0(round(df1$x),"%")
```

Next, you can plot your data using `ggplot` and adding different relevant layers.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = perc)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Good luck!